# What should be correct DB schema when input data are kinda versioned?

Tags: database-design, schema, design-pattern

I have been bit confused on how should I create a proper DB schema for my particular case - everithing I come up with is very suboptimal (duplicated columns and so). I think I'm missing right DB thinking or I can not see the problem from higher perspective.

Task we dealing with is in bio-informatics realm (but naming below is inaccurate from that point of view) - entities we work with are like this:

- There is a **protein** - e.g. `1tqn`
- Every protein have 1 or more **chains** (about 1 - 20 per protein) - e.g. `A`
- Every chain consist of 1 or more **domains** (about 1 - 5 per chain, below 500k in total) - e.g. `00`, so full domain name is `1tqnA00`

And also:

- There is a **family** which is a group of domains (about 7k of them) - e.g. `1.10.630.10`
- And each family have 1 or more **subfamiles** and it groups one or more domains (about 32k of them) - e.g. `1.10.630.10.25`

This is quite simple, but then there is a **version**: all of above changes in time and we compute some data based on weekly "snapshots" (i.e. these versions), so if `1tqnA00` is in `1.10.630.10.25` at one week, it can be in `1.10.10.10.55` next week and another week it can be deleted at all. Usually about 10% of families changes every week by moving very small part of the domains to another family.

Most usual queries would be:

- What is the latest version for family XYZ?
- What is the list of domains in family XYZ in version ABC?
- What is the latest version for domain XYZ?
- What is the family for domain XYZ in version ABC?

Some points I'm not certain about:

- Should I split all these entities into separate tables and interconnect with foreign keys when I'll be only tracking names of these entities and not any additional metadata?
- Should I be using numerical primary keys, or is string (name of the entity) OK given sizes above?

How should the schema reflect this "versioning" of input data? As of now, we are running on SQLite, but plan to migrate to PostgreSQL soon. Thank you very much for ideas.